# How to get an element to hide/unhide through DOM without using ID?

Tags: javascript

```
  var onoffbutton = document.getElementById("onoffInput");
  onoffbutton.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    if(document.getElementById("demoE").innerHTML==="first"){
    document.getElementById("demoE").innerHTML ="second";
    document.getElementsByClassName('animation').hidden = false;
    return;
    }
    if(document.getElementById("demoE").innerHTML==="second"){
    document.getElementById("demoE").innerHTML ="first";
    document.getElementsByClassName('animation').hidden = true;
    return;
    }
    } , false)
```

When I use `document.getElementsByClassName('animation').hidden = false;` it doesn't work, but when I use `document.getElementById('animation').hidden = false` it helps me unhide an image.  The problem is that I have an image that already has an ID attached to it.

`<img class="animation" src="gifs/right.gif" hidden>` vs. `<img class="animation" id="original-pick" hidden>`  Notice I have two selectors attached to the second element.  Thanks!

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName` return an array.. try `var elm = document.getElementsByClassName('animation');elm[0].hidden = false;`

Answer (score 0):

I think the best option is to use `document.querySelector(...)`:

```
document.querySelector(".animation").hidden = false;
```

More documentation of this feature can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).

Comment: Knowing how to search stackoverflow is key too!  To sort from revelance to number of votes and to see the different ways of getting at the same question (can sort with relevance, # etc).